# Regex match strings with different values

Tags: regex

```
for i,v in array

for i   ,    v      in array

for i , v in array

for i,         v in array

for i,v               in array

for  i, v in array
```

```
for[\s+,.](.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Vd3w7C/2

How i could match anything after the `v`

**but**

`i`,`v`, and `in array` will have different values

i mean something like:
`for ppp,gflgkf heekd gfvb`

Comment: Like this? `\bfor [^\s,]+(?:\s*,\s*[^\s,]+)*\s*(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/caOndn/1

Comment: Closer, this example: `for  i, v in array` was not caught, my fault, i have add it to the topic

Comment: Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/cle7Tf/1

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\bfor\s+[^\s,]+(?:\s*,\s*[^\s,]+)*\s+(.+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bfor\s+` Match `for` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitspace char or `,`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s*,\s*[^\s,]+` Match a comma between optional whitespace chars, and match at least a single char other than a comma or whitespace chars
- `)*\s+` Close the group and optionally repeat it followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `(.+)` Capture 1+ times any char except a newline in **group 1**

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/POg6MI/1).

Comment: @Frank: Consider marking this answer as accepted as it solves your problem

Comment: Nice +! Here is a thought/something to consider. In any programming language (that I know of) the valid names of variables, functions etc. are made up out of word-characters. It's the main reason `\w` exists in the first place. So it *should* be safe to swap `[^\s,]` for `\w`.

Comment: @JvdV Yes you are right, that actually was my first thought as well. But when I saw the character class used in the question, I negated it excluding only the comma.